# Why is daterangepicker using every field type?

Tags: jquery

I've just tried the daterangepicker and for some reason it uses every form and button I have on my site. Why is this? Is there a better alternative? Thanks :)))

[Here's what I have](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: In the future, please post your code in the description rather than just providing an external link.

Comment: I apologize for that! I was just clueless as to what is and what is not important to show in regards to this plugin as I am new to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that plugin does not properly handle selectors that target multiple elements.

Just as a quick work-around, try this (not tested, but should work):

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).daterangepicker({arrows:false});
}
```

Note that this will apply the picker to all input elements, but each one is controlled individually rather than all inputs being updated by a single picker.

If you wish to target only a single input, you need to give that input a unique ID or class and update your selector to target it (e.g. #my_datepicker or .my_datepicker)

Comment: Thanks simshaun!  The code works, but when I tried to update my selector it seems to apply each input again: $('input').each(function() {
    $('#rangeA').daterangepicker({arrows:false});
}

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this above, but if you are only targeting a single input, it needs to replace the `$('input')` selector.  Try just `$('#rangeA').daterangepicker({arrows:false});` without the `$('input').each()` wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the function below. You are using $('input') as the selector, which means all input elements. Since you have 3 input elements on your form and all 3 of them get the daterangepicker. For selectively applying it to elements, change your selector to be an id or class i.e. $('#myId').daterangepicker() or $('.myclass').daterangepicker().

```
$(function(){
              $('input').daterangepicker({arrows:false}); 
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

this piece of code: `$('input')` selects all elements with a `tagName` of input. That is why the plugin is applied to all elements with a `tagName` of input.